# Adding leaflet marker with nested array, getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of null

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I know this is a common error but I'm not seeing my specific problem. Doing a little basic JS practice and running into this error only when using a nested array of coordinate pairs. If I only try and map one single location the error goes away. Any thoughts as to why this might be happening? Code below.

```
    var options = {
      center: [39.8333,-98.5833],
      zoom: 4
    }
    // instantiate the leaflet object
    var map = L.map('map', options);

    // Get basemap URL from Leaflet Providers
    var basemap_url = 'http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}'

    // Get basemap attributes from Leaflet Providers
    var basemap_attributes = {
      attribution: 'Tiles &copy; Esri &mdash; Source: Esri, DeLorme, NAVTEQ, USGS, Intermap, iPC, NRCAN, Esri Japan, METI, Esri China (Hong Kong), Esri (Thailand), TomTom, 2012'
    }

    // Add tileset as a layer in our map by passing as arguments to  tileLayer method
    var tiles = L.tileLayer(basemap_url, basemap_attributes);

    // add tiles to map with addLayer method
    map.addLayer(tiles);

    // variable to hold string value of cities
    var cities = ["Victoria", "Bettles", "Truth or Consequences"];
    var cityCoords = [
    [48.430077, -123.353043],
    [66.905857, -151.533330],
    [33.1284, -107.25283]
  ];
    var cityPops = [92141, 13, 5948];
    var cityCapitals = [true, false, false];

    // loop through all the elements in the cities array
    for(let i = 0; i <= cities.length; i++){
      let cityName = cities[i];
      let cityPop = cityPops[i];
      let cityCap = cityCapitals[i];
      let namePop = `<b>${cityName}</b><br> population: <b>${cityPop}</b><br>`;
     
      let popup = `${cityName} population: ${cityPop}`
      console.log(popup)

      if (cityCap == true) {
        popup += 'is a capital city'}

      L.marker(cityCoords).addTo(map)
        .bindPopup(popup);
    }
```

Comment: try `L.marker(cityCoords[i])` to pass an entry in the coordinates array to [`marker`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-0.7.7.html#marker)

Comment: @traktor53 - that worked. This grabs all the arrays that are recognized in the loop. Thank you!

Comment: What's with the parallel arrays? Why not `var cities = [{name: "Victoria", coords: [48.430077, -123.353043], population: 92141, capital: true}, // etc...]`

Comment: For mapping applications I was taught to use nested arrays.

Answer (score 0):

As commented, replacing

```
   L.marker(cityCoords).addTo(map)
```

with

```
   L.marker(cityCoords[i]).addTo(map)
```

solves the problem by passing a [`LatLng`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-0.7.7.html#latlng) array of numbers to [`marker`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-0.7.7.html#marker) as covered in documentation.

I deduce that Leaflet converts an array of arrays to `null` if the array should have contained numeric coordinate values, and then generates errors trying to access `lat` or `lng` properties of what should have been a valid conversion result.